# Linux all files of folder modified yesterday

Tags: linux, command, last-modified

I have modified some files present in various folders in my webroot. This was development environment. Now I have to find all files modified yesterday to migrate to productions.

Is there any way (Linux command) to list only those files modified yesterday in my webroot tree?

Comment: I thought you said you were looking for files modified yesterday?  So why did you accept an answer that gives you the files modified today?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`find ./ -mtime -1`

Finds everything, what was modified in the current directory at the last 24 hours.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. Question was about finding files modified yesterday, not in the last 24 hours.

Answer (score 26):

```
find . -daystart -mtime 1 -print
```

This gets just files modified YESTERDAY - ie: today is Jun 21, only files for Jun 20 are found.

(-mtime takes a '-', a '+', or an explicit number of exact days).

If you want a long listing, substitute

```
-exec ls -ld \;
```

for the

```
-print.
```

Comment: This comment makes a lot of sense today.

Answer (score 5):

```
find . -mtime +2 -prune -o -mtime +1 -print
```

This does a find but excludes anything that was modified more than two days ago, then finds anything that was modified more than one day ago.

Comment: Why not just use -mtime +1 ?

Comment: @IvailoBardarov because that finds everything that was modified 1 day OR MORE ago, and the question was about things that were modified 1 day ago.

Comment: The prune makes this super fast. If you're working on a huge NFS this is the way to go